# Live-action wuxia TV series about two brothers who were demigods with special powers

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember when I was a kid (I think in 2004), I watched this live-action wuxia TV series on DVD in the US about two brothers who were demigods with special powers. The youngest had eyes that could see through anything, and they had two swords that would get stronger when put together as an 'X.'

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was this?  (We don't know when you were a kid.)  Live-action or animated?  TV series or series of movies?

Comment: I dont remember when the show came out but I think saw it in 2004 so it must have came out before then

Comment: It was also a live-action tv show

Comment: @user152079 - Which country did you watch this in?

Comment: the show was chinese I believe, I watched it on dvd in the US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Mystery of the Twin Swords](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11405260/)*** (1991)...?

From [DramaWiki](https://wiki.d-addicts.com/Mystery_of_the_Twin_Swords):

> The series tells the story of two brothers, Ah Yat (Roger Kwok) and Ah Yuet (Dicky Cheung) and the battle between the immortals and devils. After giving birth to Ah Yat, the immortals are informed that the next child will represent them in the next dual of the century against the devils. So, the head devil then turns the unborn baby into his, believing that by turning the immortals' representative into the devils', he will be able to take control of him and cause the two brothers to fight and cause the universe to collapse. However, the two brothers suddenly disappears after Ah Yuet's birth, and are discovered by a granny with mystical powers.
>
> She raises them for 20 years with her daughter, Kiu Kiu (Chan On Ying), whom the brothers sees as a sister. While growing up, the two brothers becomes cheeky, arrogant, but witty and clever with their tricks. Their playful personality leads them down the mountain where their adventure involves the new people they meet, including their love potential Ching Ching (Carol Yeung), the hitman Yin Pin Tin (Lau Ka Fai) and a thief Kong Ling (Ng Wing Hung). But after all the fun of their journey, the brothers eventually face each other in the battle of the century between the immortals and devils where only one are expected to live.

At the end of the intro, shown in the video below, the two brothers cross their swords, producing a burst of electricity.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct show